# What is the name of this property for a set of integers?

Tags: integers

A random list of integers is sorted.  There is an integer N in the list such that there are N or more integers in the list whose value matches or exceeds N.  For example, consider the list {1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 11, 14, 15, 17, 23, 24, 26} for which N = 8 since there are eight elements in the list whose value meets or exceeds 8. The elements 1, 3, 4, and 7 also work but 8 is the largest for which this works.  The element 11 does not work since there are only seven elements in the list whose value meets or exceeds 11.  I believe that it is named after the mathematician who studied it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the $h$-index, typically used for ranking academic publication output. See [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-index). Apparently this is named after the physicist Jorge Hirsch, and can be called the Hirsch index or Hirsch number.

Answer (score 0):

Kundor is very correct.  The h-index is based on the quantity for which I was searching.  That number is called the **Eddington Number** named after Arthur Eddington (1882-1944) the British physicists and mathematician.  Apparently it is applied to cycling but can be applied to any set (as is the case with the h-index).  Thanks to all.